# How to remove the last blank row in the EXT.list.Listview of extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using ListView of extjs to insert a list of values, after creating the list and when i 
try to modify the listview, i surprised seeing a blank row added to the list at last.
Code:

```
var listView = new Ext.list.ListView({
  id: "listView_values",
  autoScroll : true,
  height:80,
  reserveScrollOffset: true,
  hideHeaders : true,
  singleSelect : true,
  store: store,
  multiSelect: false,
  columns: [{
     dataIndex: 'value'
  }]
});
```

PLease help in solving this issue.

Comment: Please post some code how exactly you're modifying the list

Comment: what is the data you are filling the list with?

Comment: @AMember i am filling the list with metadata(List kind of data)

Comment: U need to give us something we can work with. Post the data or the modification u r trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding this piece of code in my java class, i achieved the above functionality.

```
lValuesList = lValuesList.substring(0, lValuesList.length() - 1);
```